# jQuery cycle just stopped working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm having a little problem with jQuery

```
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>            
 <script    src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
 <script> $('.rotator').cycle({ fx: 'fade', timeout: 7000 }); </script>
 </head>

<body>

<div class="rotator">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
<img src="4.jpg">
</div>

</body>
```

Was working fine earlier today then it just stopped working? is there something wrong?

Comment: did you change the code in any way before it stopped working?

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: You need to put the jquery code in `$(document).ready()` DOM handler

Comment: No changes to the code.. Huangism
uptownnickbrown .. it is showing all of the pictures in a line not cycling thru them.
I will try that karthikr

Comment: Sorry for the bad question and thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 6):

```
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js
```

Gives me an `Access Denied`. Something tells me that link shouldn't be used as a CDN.

I'd say go [download cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html), place it in your website's directory then include *that* reference, and don't use github as a CDN.

If you *really* want it hosted elsewhere, either look on [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/) and, if it's not already there, ask them to add it.

As a final note, you should *never* rely on a CDN hosting the only version of a library--always have a local backup. You see this commonly wiht jQuery to the effect of:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"><'+'/script'>');</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this was the problem and it is now fixed.